# Jquery, Not on hover but always?

Tags: jquery, hover

I've got this little piece of Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Caption Sliding (Partially Hidden to Visible)
    $('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
        $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'90px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
    }, function() {
        $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'120px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
    });
});
```

And it works but on hover, the piece of Opacity comes on the picture en on mouse out it goes down, but i've to get:

```
$(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'90px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
```

this has to be when not hovered how to?

Comment: What? Do you want 90px on hover and 120px on mouseout? Why don't you just switch them?

Comment: Nop, i want it on 90px on normalstate, so when it's not touched with a mouse.

Comment: If you want to style the non-hovered, non-active, state then just use CSS to style the elements. There's no point relying on jQuery or any other JavaScript for this...

Comment: Look, i want to have that piece of text on 90px of the top, and when you hover, it'll go to 120px of the top. en on mouse out, back to 90px;

Comment: Exactly, so just switch?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, just set the initial style in your css:

```
.boxgrid.caption .cover{
    top: 90px;
}
```

And swap the code in your hover.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
            $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'120px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
        }, function() {
            $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'90px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you've set it to go 90px when hovering, and 120px when the mouse goes out. From your description it sounds like you want the reverse so just swap the two numbers.

When you ask how to make 90px the "normal" state, do you mean when it has not yet been touched by the mouse at all? If so add this line to your document ready before or after your hover handler:

```
$(".cover", this).css({top:'90px'});
```

Putting it all together:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cover", this).css({top:'90px'});

        //Caption Sliding (Partially Hidden to Visible)
        $('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
            $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'120px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
        }, function() {
            $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'90px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
        });
    });
```

This assumes you have to do it all in JavaScript for some reason and can't just set the default state in your style sheet with

`.boxgrid.caption .cover { top : 90px; }`

Comment: Nop, on NOT HOVER and when your mouse didn't touch it, then it has to be 90px from top, when mouse hovered 120px and when mouse out 90px. So only on hover just 30px higher. Clear enough?

Comment: Isn't that what I said, and what my code does? And also what the code in James's answer does?